# AWS Cape Town Region, no free tier option on SQL Server RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Updated: See screenshots below

In the Cape Town (Africa) region - I am **unable** to create a free tier micro instance RDS using SQL Server on AWS.

Steps that I followed:

- Using root user
- I go to RDS, click on databases and then on create database
- Engine Options: Microsoft SQL Server
- Edition: SQL Server Express Edition
- Version: Choose the latest version (2019)
- Settings: I leave as is (Choose Auto generate password)
- DB Instance Class: NO MICRO OPTION????

Region is important, it has to be **Cape Town (Africa)**

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, were trying to follow documentation step by step.

Please Advise

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cJny.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etfys.png)

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJn4k.png)

[Step 4: Initial Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IaOg.png)

[Step 5: When I click on dropdown arrow (nothing to select)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p66MZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose **SQL Server 2017 version 14**, not 2019 version 15. Once you do this you will be able to use t2.micro for it.

From the list [here](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/previous-generation/), it seems that Cape Town (Africa) region **does not support** at all db.t2 type instances.

Comment: Hi, this does not work. If I use the original interface and chose only free tier options and SQL Server 2017 v.14 then there is no drop down in Database Instance Class.

Comment: @Jan Can you update your question with some screenshots? its not clear what you are trying to describe.

Comment: Updated: Screenshots added

Comment: @Jan From what is listed [here](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/previous-generation/) t2 are not supported at all in your region. I can only update the answer with this info.

Comment: According to AWS documentation Free Tier is supported in all regions and for those that does not have t2, then t3 has free tier supported.